# Não encontra o angular

Tags: ionic3

Olá amigos desenvolvedores estou iniciando um projeto com o Ionic3, angular e firebase, mas estou tendo uma dor de cabeça pq do nada o meu projeto parou de abrir na página home e está indo direto para outra página e apresentando o seguinte erro. Eu ainda sou iniciante nesse negócio de Ionic e estou meio perdido sem saber resolver. Quem puder me ajudar agradeço infinitamente.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou instalar novamente ? `npm install @angular/cli`

Comment: vou tentar mano.

Comment: ainda o mesmo erro.